# How to remove objects from a list using a list of indexes on python?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a DataFrame from which I wanted to randomly select 20% of the data to use as test data. However, I need to remove said data from my original set to use as training data.
I have a list of the indexes the random sample is made up from (indexes of the original DF). When i use a for loop and the function .pop() the indexes change so the elements been removed after that the first iteration are not the ones that are in my test data frame. I need help to remove the data from the first data frame but no functions will take a list of indexes as an argument. What can i do about this? Is there a way to subtract a data from from another?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions to this problem. You could...

- Iterate in reverse
- Create another array to store the values
- Use list comprehension

An example of the third method is as follows.

Let's say that you want to remove all 2's from an array:

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1]
new_data = [n for n in data if n != 2]
# new_data = [1, 3, 1]
```

In my past experience this is always the method I use when cleaning/reconstructing arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question,

> Is there a way to subtract a data from from another?

You can simply drop the indexes belonging to `Test` from the primary DataFrame to get your `Train`. Try this -

```
train = df.drop(test.index, axis=0)

#Where df is the main dataset from which test data has been sampled.
#train, test, df are all pd.DataFrames
```

However, if you are preparing data for a machine learning problem, I would recommend some better methods, as discussed in the next part of my answer.

---

#### 1. Using Sklearn API (Recommended)

You could try using the `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` api to save you a lot of time in doing such train test splits.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,10)))

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2)
train.shape, test.shape
```

```
((80, 10), (20, 10))
```

#### 2. Using pandas methods

Another way is to sample 20% data from df and then filter the rest for train.

```
test = df.sample(frac=0.2)
train = df.loc[~df.index.isin(test.index)]
train.shape, test.shape
```

```
((80, 10), (20, 10))
```

#### 3. Starting with a list of indexes

Let's say you already have a list of indexes (test_idx), as you mention in your question. In that case, you can still work with pandas methods to do this without any `for` loops or `pop()`

```
test_idx = np.random.choice(range(100), 20, replace=False) #approx 20% random indexes 

test = df.loc[df.index.isin(test_idx)]
train = df.loc[~df.index.isin(test_idx)]
train.shape, test.shape
```

```
((80, 10), (20, 10))
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very useful!